# No registration chess

Tags: software, online-chess

Are there any free, either email or possibly peer to peer turn based, chess pc apps that look decent?
I'm looking to play with a friend directly, not have to go through registration, and not in real time.

Answer (score 3):

How about

http://en.lichess.org/

I just found it. There is a "Play with a friend" option and you can send a URL to a friend and play without having to register.

Comment: That looks incredibly nice. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

Not an app, but very nice if you don't need many bells and whistles is http://www.apronus.com/chess/wbeditor.php

I recently used it to play a correspondence game with a friend via messenger. You play on the right board and use the "link to share" button to create a link like: http://www.apronus.com/chess/wbeditor.php?m=e4_d5_exd5_Qxd5_Nf3
As you can see, that link contains the move history, so it's easy to play by sending back and forth the link created after your move. You can even export PGN and FEN files whenever you feel like it to import somewhere else.